# Work arounds for Matlab yyaxis limitations?

Tags: matlab, plot

I upgraded from Matlab 2015b to 2019a and was notified that `plotyy` is no longer recommended.  Function `yyaxis` is recommended instead.  However, I can't seem to get it to treat a `grouped` `BarLayout` properly:

```
close all; clear
BarSeries = [2 5 8;9 6 3]'
xData = [1 4 7]';
myBarFn = @(x,y) bar( x,y, 'BarLayout','grouped' , 'BarWidth',1 );
   % Customized bar function

% Using plotyy
v0 = [0 0 0]'; % Dummy zeros
figure(1)
ax = plotyy( xData , [ BarSeries(:,1) v0             ] , ...
             xData , [ v0             BarSeries(:,2) ] , ...
             myBarFn , myBarFn );
title('Using plotyy');
set( gcf, 'Position' , [0 100 288 235] );

% Using yyaxis
figure(2)
yyaxis left;
ax = gca;
myBarFn( xData, BarSeries(:,1) );
yyaxis right;
myBarFn( xData, BarSeries(:,2) );
title('Using yyaxis');
set( gcf, 'Position' , [300 100 288 235] );
```

[image]  [image]

This is just dummy data, but the real data will have very different value ranges for the two bar series.  So I need two y-axes.  Is a way to achieve the `grouped` `BarLayout` using `yyaxis` instead of `plotyy`?

Comment: `plotyy` and `yyaxis` are not intended for this kind of use: they are intended to activate left and right y axis, possibly with two different scales (see your picture on the right). Do you want to achieve two different y-scales as a primary result?
----
also check this: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/420864-problem-in-plotting-bar-graph-with-two-y-axis-bars-overlapping

Comment: Yes, the real data will have different scales, which is the reason for going to two y-axes.  The examples you cited are not ways to get the same effect using `yyaxis`.  If I cannot do this with `yyaxis`, then I feel that it would be easier to simply use `plotyy`.  Before doing so, however, I just wanted to check whether there was a simple solution that I was overlooking.

Comment: Do you need different _y_-scales (8 and 10) as with `yyaxis`,  or the same scale (10 in both cases) as with `plotyy`? Would `bar(xData, BarSeries, 1)` be enough?

Comment: Yes, the real data will have very different value ranges.  This is why I need 2 y-axes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this is what you want. I have used your code with `yyaxis`, changing only the two lines marked as `%%% Changed`:

```
close all; clear
BarSeries = [2 5 8;9 6 3].';
xData = [1 4 7]';
myBarFn = @(x,y) bar( x,y, 'BarLayout','grouped' , 'BarWidth',1 );
   % Customized bar function

% Using yyaxis
figure
yyaxis left;
ax = gca;
myBarFn( xData, [BarSeries(:,1) NaN(size(BarSeries,1), 1)] ); %%% Changed
yyaxis right;
myBarFn( xData, [NaN(size(BarSeries,1), 1) BarSeries(:,2)] ); %%% Changed
title('Using yyaxis');
set( gcf, 'Position' , [300 100 288 235] );
```

[image]

Comment: That approach mirrors the scheme of `plotyy` in that it overlays two plots, each of a dual bar series.  In each plot, one of the two bar series is dummy data.  I guess this is useful if support for `plotyy` is ever ended, but for now, it seems that `plotyy` (or some emulation thereof) is the way to go.  Thanks.